# Return with "?:" operator

Tags: c++, return

So I have to do a simple program for my college class, which would include a structure `fraction` with numerator and denominator as `ints` and a function `is_correct()` checking two conditions: is denominator`!=0` and is nominator`<`denominator. If two of them are true, then I should return `true`, otherwise `false`. I'm obligated to use `?:` operator. So here's my code:

```
struct fraction {int n,d;
                bool is_correct(){
                    d!=0?(return n<d?true:false):return false;
                };
                };
```

I mean, I guess I could use one `if` with condition `d!=0`, but I have to use only `?:`, and `g++` gives me that: `expected primary-expression before 'return'`

Comment: The ternary expression is an expression and can't handle statements. `return` can only be used in statements, not in expressions.

Comment: Your edit moved your question into the territory of too broad or unclear.  Even if it didn't though, [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/2792531) are discouraged.  If you want to ask another question, mark an accepted answer here and post a new question.  As such, I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: Since you're obliged to use the ternary operator ('?:', not '?'), you're ending up with rather silly things like `return n < d ? true : false`. There's no need to translate the boolean expression `n < d` into `true` or `false` since it already has that value; `return n < d` does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If two of them are true, then I should return true, otherwise false

This is a pretty standard truth table, right?

```
   | T | F
---+---+---
 T | T | F
---+---+---
 F | F | F
```

And I know an operator that has an identical truth table: `&&`.

We don't need a ternary here at all.  We can simply write:

```
return d != 0 && n < d;
```

An even more concise solution looks like this:

```
return d && n<d;
```

But I'll make the case that the first solution more clearly expresses the coder's intent, which is an important consideration.

Comment: Even simpler is:  `return d && n<d;`.

Comment: If you're most interested in fixing the syntax problem in your code as it regards to ternary statements, you should mark one of the other answers as accepted.  If you are interested in creating clean and concise code, then you should consider this simply, readable solution.

Comment: @l3x Perhaps, but I think that `d != 0` expresses intent slightly better (especially if you want to consider people reading this coming from other languages that don't allow integers to be treated as bools like this).  But a valid point nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Just move the `return` outside of the condition (spacing added for clarity):

```
return d != 0 ? (n < d ? true : false) : false;
```

Comment: `return d != 0 ? (n < d) : false;`

Comment: You could even do `d != 0 && n < d`, but I was just copying OP's code.

Comment: Indeed, I was about to write an answer with that code actually.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct fraction {
  int n,d;

  bool is_correct() {
    return d != 0 ? (n < d ? true : false) : false;
  };
};
```